# I'm trying to copy a cell from one workbook and paste as values to a different workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy a cell from one workbook and paste as values to a different workbook

```
' Copy from Source book.sheet.cell, Paste to Destination book.sheet.cell

Workbooks("SOURCE.xlsx").Worksheets("SOURCE").Range("C2").Copy _
Workbooks("DESTINATION.xlsm").Worksheets("DESTINATION 1").Range("F4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

I'm getting a compile error using .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Comment: Remove the `_` at the end of the first line. If you're using `PasteSpecial`, it is a separate line from the `Copy`. Right now you only have *one* statement because you're using the line continuation character.

Comment: Genius! Thank You!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code has to reference these seperate books various times, it would greatly help to simplify by creating some short hand variables. You can `Set` your books/sheets right off the bat. Then, anytime you want to refer to a book, you can call the variable for it rather the lengthy direct string.

The below goes for a value transfer rather a copy/paste. Either way, the final result is better for readability which goes a long way when you need to update/troubleshoot down the road.

---

```
Sub Simplify()

'SS = Source Sheet
'DS = Destination Sheet

Dim SS As Worksheet: Set SS = Workbooks("SOURSE.xlsx").Worksheets("SOURCE")
Dim DS As Worksheet: Set DS = Workbooks("DESTINATION.xlsm").Worksheets("DESTINATION 1")

DS.Range("F4").Value = SS.Range("C2").Value

End Sub
```

---

Copy and paste....

```
SS.Range("C2").Copy
DS.Range("F4").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: That's Great! Thank You, urdearboy!

Comment: Thanks so much.I had to look through my code to see how I rewrote it. I did rewrite it using your suggestion.

Can you look at my other question on my profile to see what I'm doing wrong?